# Printing expression values inside comments in Jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Need to print the value of a parameter inside a Jade template comment. The value is passed-in correctly; the following works as expected:

```
if type !== "surveyFree"
    ul.pollOptions
        for answer, idx in answers
            li
                +printAnswer(answer, idx)
else
    textarea(cols="50", rows="4", placeholder="Type in your answer")
```

However, all attempts to print out the value of the `type` variable inside a comment have failed. I've tried the following forms:

```
// "type = " + type
// #{"type = " + type}
// span= #{"type = " + type}
// span= type = #{type}
```

and many others, but nothing works (everything gets printed exactly as I typed it in). I'd like the output:

```
<!-- type = challenge -->
```

or

```
<!-- type = survey -->
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this way will be good for you:

```
!='<!-- COMMENT VARAIBLE: ' + variable + '-->'
```